# Checking time in trigger before updating,inserting,or deleting

Tags: oracle, plsql

I would like to create a trigger that store Who(Names) as the Loged User, Action as what he/she has done, And the Time he/she made it. But Also it should be capable of revolking the changes when it's not Working Time for example working time can be (from 8H:00 AM to 05:00 PM). So Tried to create it.

// This is the Table to Store the Log named "System_events"

```
create table system_events (who varchar2(10),action varchar2(10), when date);
```

Actually the trigger will check and save any change on a table named students

//Codes to create that trigger

```
create or replace trigger all_actions
before insert or update or delete on students
declare
user_action system_events.action%type;
begin
if INSERTING then
user_action :='Insert';
elsif UPDATING then
user_action :='Update';
elsif DELETING then
user_action :='Delete';
else
raise_application_error (-20001, 'Yous should never get this error.');
end if;
insert into system_events(who,action,when) values(user,user_action,sysdate);
end;
```

So this trigger I created is working. However it doesn't check the Time. So I would like to add that feature of checking the Time and revolke the change if it's not in the right time

Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

It is not clear what do you mean by "revolke the change". I assume you want to stop the users from doing any DML operation except during work hours. If so, you could add another `IF` condition and raise an exception for times beyond 8am - 5pm.

```
CREATE OR replace TRIGGER all_actions 
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON students 
DECLARE 
    user_action system_events.action%TYPE; 
BEGIN 
    IF inserting THEN 
      user_action := 'Insert'; 
    ELSIF updating THEN 
      user_action := 'Update'; 
    ELSIF deleting THEN 
      user_action := 'Delete'; 
    ELSE 
      raise_application_error (-20001, 'You should never get this error.'); 
    END IF; 

    IF to_number(to_char(SYSDATE, 'HH24')) NOT BETWEEN 8 AND 16 THEN 
      raise_application_error (-20001, 'You should not do ' 
                                       ||user_action 
                                       ||' operation during this time.'); 
    END IF; 

    INSERT INTO system_events 
                (who, 
                 action, 
                 when) 
    VALUES      (USER, 
                 user_action, 
                 SYSDATE); 
END; 
/
```

*Note*: You may put this `IF` condition before checking the operation type as well if you want, without `user_action`

Comment: Thanks for your Answer @Kaushik Nayak, I was just trying to say that the trigger should prevent any operation including inserting,deleting and updating when it not working hours... But in any case you got it right and you gave me the right solution.

Comment: @Lenz Vital : you're welcome. please accept the answer as right. it would help the people seeking answers to similar questions